# ArrayList Lottery Game

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to create a Lottery Number Generator. It will ask the user how many games they want to play then create a Lottery Ticket with randomly picked numbers 1-49. Each game will be stored. Once all games have been created then it will print it out. Right now I'm having an issue where the Games are not copying into the ArrayList the way I want it. Currently it places them all into the element then copies that element "numberOfGames" times. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the for loop but I'm stuck on this part.

```
public class LotteryTicket {

ArrayList<Integer> Numbers;
ArrayList<Integer> Lottery;
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> Games;


LotteryTicket(){
    Lottery = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Games = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
}

public ArrayList<Integer> Numbers(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 49; i++){
        Numbers.add(i);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(Numbers);
    return Numbers;
}
public void Generate(int numberOfGames){
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfGames; i++){
        Numbers();
        for(int x = 0; x < 6; x++){
            Lottery.add(Numbers.get(x));                
        }
        Collections.sort(Lottery);
        Games.add(Lottery);
    }
}

public void Display(){
    System.out.println(Games);
}
}
```

Here is my tester:

```
public class Picker {

private static int numberOfGames;

public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Please enter the amount of games you would like to play");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    numberOfGames = in.nextInt();
    LotteryTicket q = new LotteryTicket();
    ArrayList<ArrayList> game= new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
    q.Generate(numberOfGames);
    q.Display();
}
}
```

Comment: Please breif us what is the order of games that you want?

Comment: Order doesn't matter because it is random anyways. As long as each Lottery is stored in a separate element in Game because right now it will store them all in the same element then duplicate that element x amount of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate Lottery for every iteration.

Try this:-

```
public void Generate(int numberOfGames){
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfGames; i++){
        Numbers();
        Lottery = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int x = 0; x < 6; x++){
            Lottery.add(Numbers.get(x));                
        }
        Collections.sort(Lottery);
        Games.add(Lottery);
    }
}
```

EDIT:-

You can avoid the same scenario for Numbers collection as well and also for performance you can initializes 1 to 49 numbers in the Numbers collection from the constructor only once and for each game iteration in your generate method you can just shuffle the Numbers and then add it to Lottery. This avoids unnecessary adding of numbers to Numbers collection

```
LotteryTicket(){
    Lottery = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Games = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    Numbers(); // call this once from constructor as the total numbers in the Numbers collection is fixed which is from 1 to 49.
}

public ArrayList<Integer> Numbers(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 49; i++){
        Numbers.add(i);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(Numbers);
    return Numbers;
}
public void Generate(int numberOfGames){
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfGames; i++){
        Collections.shuffle(Numbers); // shuffle the numbers for every game
        Lottery = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // create a new Lottery ticket
        for(int x = 0; x < 6; x++){
            Lottery.add(Numbers.get(x));                
        }
        Collections.sort(Lottery);
        Games.add(Lottery);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay that worked perfectly. Thanks, didn't realize had to do that but makes sense now since if I didn't I'm just adding more numbers into Lottery.

Comment: What I did was I did the for loop in the constructor instead of having a method for it. Is it better to have a method for it or just creating it in the constructor?

Comment: @user2782582 that should be fine. Also one suggestion on the naming conventions :- All the variables and method names in Java start with smaller case.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I see is that you are not emptying your Numbers and Lottery array from game to game, resulting in the previous numbers already being there.

Try this:

```
public void Generate(int numberOfGames){
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfGames; i++){
        Numbers();
        for(int x = 0; x < 6; x++){
            Lottery.add(Numbers.get(x));                
        }

        //reset the array the numbers array so we can re add numbers after.
        Numbers.clear();
        Collections.sort(Lottery);
        Games.add(Lottery);

        //reset the lottery array so we can have a new lottery after.
        Lottery.clear();
    }
}
```

This will be a quick fix. For a better one. Try initializing your "Numbers" only once in your constructor (you don't need new numbers every time you run a game, do you?)